# How to animate tabLayout dots

Tags: android, animation, android-tablayout

I have a viewPager with tabLayout like this:

[image: Dots]

I need to animate dots when sliding pages with zoom in animation (scale selected dot to her original size).

I have TabLayout element with **app:tabBackground** drawable xml file:

```
<animated-selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/on"
        android:drawable="@drawable/selected_dot"
        android:state_selected="true" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/off"
        android:drawable="@drawable/default_dot" />

    <transition
        android:fromId="@id/off"
        android:toId="@+id/on">
        <animation-list>
            <!-- here I stuck -->
        </animation-list>
    </transition>
</animated-selector>
```

And tabLayout is connected with viewPager in this way:

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

The dot is just a shape element, so **selected_dot.xml** looks like this:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape
        android:innerRadius="0dp"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thickness="8dp"
        android:useLevel="false">
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

I think that I need animation resource file this to create zoom-in and zoom-out animation, so I created **scale.xml** file as anim resource

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:fillAfter="true" >
    <scale
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromXScale="0.5"
        android:fromYScale="0.5"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="1"
        android:toYScale="1" >
    </scale>
</set>
```

**But how** I can apply it to the dots? I thought that I can add animation inside **transition** tag in tabLayout drawable, but no success. Also I tried to do it programmatically in viewPager's onPageChangeListener, but I don't know how to represent shape (selected dot) as a view to start animation. I tried `tabLayout.getTabAt(position).getCustomView().startAnimation(...);` but getCustomView() returns null.

Thanks for any help and sorry for my English!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers, I finally found a solution which may be not so perfect but fully working. Now all dots have same xml layout (selected_dot.xml) and I adjust dot's size by scaling it

```
        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout) as TabLayout
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)


        val vg = tabLayout.getChildAt(0) as ViewGroup

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
            override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
                val a = vg.getChildAt(tab.position)
                a.animate()
                        .scaleX(1f)
                        .scaleY(1f)
                        .setInterpolator(FastOutSlowInInterpolator())
                        .setDuration(resources.getInteger(android.R.integer.config_mediumAnimTime).toLong())
                        .start()
            }

            override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
                val a = vg.getChildAt(tab.position)
                a.animate()
                        .scaleX(0.5f)
                        .scaleY(0.5f)
                        .setInterpolator(FastOutSlowInInterpolator())
                        .setDuration(1)  // See explanation below
                        .start()
            }

            override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
            }
        })
```

I don't need animation on unselecting so I make animation with duration 1ms. I don't know why, but simple

```
a.clearAnimation()
a.scaleX = 0.5f
a.scaleY = 0.5f
```

gives me bugs. So I choose 1ms animation.
And because of all dots use selected_dot.xml layout, I need to scale down dots on 2, 3 and 4 positions when user is launching activity

```
private fun initializeDots() {
    val vg = tabLayout.getChildAt(0) as ViewGroup
    for (i in 0 until vg.childCount) {
        if (i == tabLayout.selectedTabPosition) {
            continue
        }
        val a = vg.getChildAt(i)
        a.scaleX = 0.5f
        a.scaleY = 0.5f
    }
```

Probably I should call it inside **onCreate** method, but vg.childCount returns me 0. Because of that I call this function in **onResume**.
It works perfect now.

Answer (score -1):

Look what i would suggest is that you make different images of every instance of the bigger(selected) dot with other smaller (dis-selected) dots and Use ImageView to set these images...
Now change the images accordingly with every change of ViewPager...

Hope it helps...

Answer (score -1):

you can try this

**1. add a linear layout below your view pager like this**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="190dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/viewPagerCountDots"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
       android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

**2. crate two image thumb for  selected and unselected like this**

**nonselected_thumb**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" android:useLevel="true"
    android:dither="true">

    <size android:height="6dip" android:width="6dip"/>

    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
</shape>
```

**selected thumb**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" android:useLevel="true"
    android:dither="true">

    <size android:height="12dip" android:width="12dip"/>

    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
</shape>
```

**now in your java file add this code**

**declare your variables like this**

```
private LinearLayout pager_indicator;
private int dotsCount;
private ImageView[] dots;
```

**add this code in your onCreate() method**

```
setIndicator();

 viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            for (int i = 0; i < dotsCount; i++) {
                dots[i].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nonselected_item));
            }
            dots[position].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selected_item));
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

**now create the setIndicator() method like this**

```
private void setIndicator() {

pager_indicator = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.viewPagerCountDots);
dotsCount = adapter.getCount();
dots = new ImageView[dotsCount];

for (int i = 0; i < dotsCount; i++) {
    dots[i] = new ImageView(this);
    dots[i].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nonselected_item));

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );

    params.setMargins(4, 0, 4, 0);

    pager_indicator.addView(dots[i], params);
 }   

     dots[0].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selected_item));
}
```

**ask me in case of any query**